# Dataweave - Dynamically splitting a name field in a mappedObject

Tags: object, if-statement, dynamic, conditional-statements, dataweave

I am attempting to split a name field within my payload, I first filter it by partnerRole and then map the object, in the map I am trying to say "If the key equals 'Name1' then output the splitName function as firstName and lastName, otherwise just the normal key and value pair will do.

here is my payload:

```
 {   "Partners": [
    {
      "PartnerRole": "ZF",
      "Name1": "BVG Smith",
      "LovesGUID": "",
      "Phone": "7776668888",
      "Email": "",
      "ExternalAcct": "",
      "PaymentType": "",
      "PartnerDescription": "TCDriverInfo",
      "LoyaltyNo": "",
      "AccountGroup": "ZONC"
    }   
] 
}
```

My mapped object seems to be going haywire, here is my dataweave:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
fun splitName(Name) = Name splitBy (" ")
var driver = ((payload.Partners filter ((partner) ->
                partner.PartnerRole == 'ZF'))[0]) 
                    mapObject (value,key,index) -> do {
                        if((key) != 'Name1')
                            {(key):(value)}
                        else
                            {"firstName":splitName(value)[0], "lastName":splitName(value)[-1]}
                    }  
---
{
    driver: driver
}
```

And outputing this json:

```
{  
 "driver": {
    "PartnerRole": "ZF",
    "Name1": "AVG Smith",
    "LovesGUID": "",
    "Phone": "7776668888",
    "Email": "",
    "ExternalAcct": "",
    "PaymentType": "",
    "PartnerDescription": "ODriverInfo",
    "LoyaltyNo": "",
    "AccountGroup": "ZTNC"   } 
}
```

I want to be able to output as driver.firstName and driver.lastName.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `key` in mapObject is actually the `Key` type and is not comparable directly to the `String` type for equality. You can cast it to a String then compare i.e.

```
if((key as String) != 'Name1')
```

You can also use the `~=` operator. [Documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-operators#equality-and-relational-operators)

Although in this case you'd have to change around your if-else statement to use it.

Comment: Thats right.. It gives the desired result ` if((key as String) != 'Name1')`